# MVC Moving from one Model View to Another Model View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to move from one Model's view to another Model's view. I have a Person model and a BurnProject model. From my Person's Index view I have a "Select" link in which I would like for it to go the BurnProject's Index view. I have tried a couple of things neither have worked.

```
public ActionResult BurnProject()
    {
        //return View("~/Views/BurnProject.cshtml");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", BurnProject);
    }
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "BurnProject");` assuming the controller is `BurnProjectController`, but if its a link, why not navigate directly to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my Person's Index view I have a "Select" link in which I would
>   like for it to go the BurnProject's Index view

Why not create a link which navigates to the index action method of BurnProjectsController ?

So in your Person's index view, you may use the Html.ActionLink helper method.

```
@model Person
<h1>This is persons index view<h1>
@Html.ActionLink("Select","Index","BurnProjects")
```

This will generate html markup for an anchor tag which has `href` attribute set to `"BurnProjects/Index"`.

If you want to pass some data from the person's index view to your BurnProject index action, you can use another overload of Html.ActionLink

```
@model Person
@Html.ActionLink("Select","Index","BurnProjects",new {@id=Model.Id},null)
```

Assuming your Person entity has an `Id` property(which you want to pass the value for) and your BurnProjects index action accepts an id param

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  // return something.
}
```

Comment: I tried the second with passing some data however I get the red squiggly under "null" telling me - invalid anonymous type member declarator

Comment: I found my error. I had null inside the last bracket instead of following it.